# Display Azure blob encrypted picture on Browser

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I have a requirement to encrypt the images while uploading on Azure Blob storage so that even the authorized person with all the access would not be able to see the content. Furthermore, these encrypted images are required to be shown on Browser using Angular/React.

One solution which I can think of is to encrypt the blob & upload to Azure Blob and when images need to be displayed at browser side then decrypt & download the images locally at server side, create the URLs pointing to local folder at server and serve the content to the browser.

However this solution has a downside, in my case a user can have more than 100 images to be displayed and downloading the images first at server and then serve it locally instead of pointing the direct URL of Blob storage, would have performance impact.

Is there any better solution of doing the same. Thanks

Comment: As far as I knew, if we want to decrypt Azure blob, we should read blob content at the same time ：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob. So I think we do not have any other ways to implement it.

Comment: Thanks Jim Xu, I am planning to keep in Azure Blob now without encryption but with limited access. I don't see any other options.

Comment: Could you please tell me what you mean ` limited access`?

Comment: Generating a SAS token using AAD with Read Only Access scope.